# Create series of Events

Tags: 7, nodes

I've got the following task:
i have a site which should be used as a kind of team calendar. there are lots of people in different roles (moderator, member) and moderators can create events (in my case ordinary nodes with time field) and members can now leave comments. there is not much more functionallity behind it, so no subscription, ... for events.

the problem i'm facing right now is the creation of events. normal events which occur once in a time are no problem, but there are much events that happen in a periodic time interval, e.g. every week.

so i need a possibility to create such a series but have them all as seperate nodes, to be able to edit individual dates. think about this scenario: the regular meeting x is scheduled every sunday from 10:00 to 12:00, but somehow it need to be changed in week 23 from 11:00 to 13:00.

is there a module for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need recurring meetings like in outlook.

I think you will have to create a rule based on flags. The flag could be something like daily, weekly, bi-weekly, monthly or yearly. Once an organiser selects the flag, rule should create nodes with meeting start time in future according to which flag was set.

Also give user an option to select # of events or end duration and you can put this check in your Rule as well to limit the events it creates.

Comment: mhh seems quite good, but what about "endless" events? it would create an endless count of nodes :D so somehow i need to stop that... maybe ajust with cronjob?

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't create endless events by creating endless nodes :)  I don't think even outlook is doing such a thing. You can control the # of events or end duration by giving 2 options to organizer as I mentioned in answer. For endless events, you can add a process in cron to check events which are near their ends (like 4 more events remaining in future) but they are not ended by organizer yet. Then clone the last event and modify the event dates. This way you can control this process and don't let anyone exploit it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Date Repeat Instance module](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_repeat_instance) will allow you to break out repeating events into separate nodes when you need it.  Basically, you would just enable the Date Repeat Module and on your content type containing the date field, indicate on the date field configuration page, click to 'allow repeating dates'.

A Repeat Tab will appear on your node edit page where you can edit the individual repeating date instances on the node.